# Annotation @Autowired not working in @Controller

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

I have a controller that does not accept @Autowired at all and I can not understand why. Everything is okay with the services; they work calmly in other controllers. But UserArticleController does not want to work. Why?

[image: image controller with null values]

[image: image others controllers]

Comment: Make sure your services are annotated properly with @Service.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please don't post code as images, as it either requires clicking or become unreadable when inlined. Please just insert as text with the proper code tags. That being said, your controller method is private where it should be public.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that the method is tagged @IsAuthorArticle and my user did not have this role. This was a mistake.

Comment: That isn't the issue, the issue is that that annotation leads to AOP being used. And as your method is private it will be invoked on the proxy, instead of the actual controller. Make the method public instead of private.